Why is it more difficult to draw a flush in Short Deck poker than a full house?
Short deck poker is made of just 4 suits of 9 cards each (6 to A). The total deck size is 36.
For a full house you need 5 cards out of 8 (two different numbers).
For a regular flush (not a straight flush or royal flush) you need 5 cards out of 9 cards (there are 9 cards of the same suit).
All articles and videos online say in Short Deck poker it's more difficult to draw a flush so a flush is ranked higher than a full house (in regular poker it's the other way around). Should it be slightly easier to draw 5 cards from a possible 9 rather than 5 cards from a possible 8?

Intuition is often unreliable for these comparisons, why not just work everything out explicitly?

I should say:  the question is ill-posed.  In regular poker, a "flush" does mean five of a single suit, but we exclude straight flushes and royal flushes.  In your case...are there similar exclusions?  I don't know what high cards might look like, but do you mean to exclude straight flushes?

Just a regular flush not a straight flush.

Please edit your post to reflect that.

I've edited it. How would I work everything out explicitly?

here are the computations using a $52$ card deck.  Study these.  The same methods go through for the short deck.

Note:  a technical point.  In ordinary ($52$ card poker), in counting straights, an Ace can be either low or high.  That is $A2345$ is a straight but so is $10JQKA$.   In your situation, presumably $12345$ is a straight, but would you also count $67891$?  This won't have any impact on the qualitative results here, but depending what choices you make, you might not exactly match the wikipedia numbers.

I have no idea what you mean be a full house is $5$ out of $8$.  Given there are $9\times 4 \times 8\times {4\choose 2}=1728$ full houses and ${9\choose 5}\times 4=126$ flushes, it seems to my obvious that you are far far more likely to draw a full house than a straight.

You are right @fleablood . I got the 8 in a faulty way. For example 2,2,2,33 is a full house.  There are four 2s in the deck and four threes, that is where I wrongly got the 8 from.

Just count them.
Flushes:
There are $4$ suits that a flush may have.  And of the nine cards in the suit there are five choices of which ranks make the suit.  Therefore there are $4\times {9\choose 5}$ possible ways to get a flush.
Full Houses:
There are $9$ possible ranks the trio can be of the four suits in that rank there are ${4\choose 3}$ to pick the suits.  There are $8$ remaining possible ranks for the pair, and ${4\choose 2}$ ways to pick the suits of the pair.  So there are $9\times {4\choose 3}\times 8 \times {4\choose 2}$ ways to get a full house.
The number $9\times {4\choose 3}\times 8\times {4\choose 2}$ is very very much more than $4\times {9\choose 5}$ so drawing a full house is much much more likely.
$$4\times {9\choose 5}=4\times \frac{6\times 7\times 8\times 9}{1\times 2 \times 3\times 4}= 504$$ while $$9\times {4\choose 3}\times 8{4\choose 2}= 9\times 4\times 8\times 6= 1728$$
So a full house is over three times more likely.

You missed the fact that there are many more unique types of full houses than flushes. That is, there are only 4 types of flushes, the four suits. But there are at least $(^9_2)$ different types of full houses. This is just assuming you get a full house by having all 5 of your cards in only 2 numbers, if the order mattered then it would 9*8 = 72.
Edit:
Note that as you increase the number of cards in a suit, you start having more options for flushes. However, the number of full houses also goes up, although by less. This is not meant to be an answer as to which one is easier, just to point out what the asker missed while building the intuition that flushes should be more common. Of course, if you want a concrete answer you always have to actually do the math, as is done in other answers.

Thanks. That is a good point. I suppose when the first card is drawn the probability is the same for both cases. The order doesn't matter.  When the second card is drawn (imagine one deck for both cases) for a full house any 35 out of the remaining 35 will do. But with a regular flush only 8 of the remaining 35 will do. Then the 3rd card drawn it would be 6 out of 34 for a full house, and 7 out of 34 for a flush and so on.

I don't see how this distinguishes between the $52$ and $36$ card decks.  After all, to follow your counts, there are still only $4$ types of flushes in the larger deck, but now there are $13\times 12$ types of full houses.  Yet, in the full deck, full houses are much less probable than flushes.

Lulu, they say a full house is rarer with 52 cards, but a flush is rarer with 36 cards. That is what I want to figure out with math. You guys are better at math than me. With a 52 deck there are 4 suits, but 13 card each to get a hand of 5. With 36 cards there are also 4 suits but only 9 cards each. I can see how it would be more difficult to get a flush with the 36 card deck, but I don't understand yet how it is easier to get a full house. Maybe it's the second card drawn that makes the difference.

@Ger  Again, I don't think intuition is at all helpful here.  For instance, as the number of cards per suit go up, it turns out that $13$ is the first case for which flushes outnumber full houses.  Other than by doing the computation, I'd have had no idea that this was true.

Say there are $n≥5$ cards per suit (we are mostly interested in the cases $n=9,13$ but the general case is valuable too).
How many flushes are there?  Well, there are $4\times \binom n5$ hands in which all cards are the same suit, but we want to exclude straight flushes.  Making the convention that the Ace can be low or high, we get $$4\times \binom n5-4\times (n-3)$$
For $n\in [9,13]$ that gives the sequence $$[480,980,1816,3132,5108]$$
How many full houses are there? No technical subtleties here, there are $n$ choices for the three-of-a-kind and then $4$ ways to choose the triple.  Then there are $n-1$ choices for the pair, and $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose the pair.  Thus the number of full houses is $$24n(n-1)$$
For $n\in [9,13]$ that gives the sequence $$[1728,2160,2640,3168,3744]$$
We see that, for $n=9$, there are far more full houses than there are flushes, whereas for $n=13$ the situation is reversed.  Note that, oddly, there is a near tie when $n=12$.
As $\binom n5$ is a quintic polynomial but $n(n-1)$ is only quadratic, eventually there are far more flushes than full houses.  Writing out the numbers, we see that $n=13$, the ordinary (in the U.S. at least)  $52$ card deck, is actually the first case for which flushes outnumber full houses.

If you reduce to 4 cards per suit, you can, of course, never get a flush while you can still get a full house.
If there are five cards per suit, then there are only four flushes, and a lot more ($20\cdot 24=480$) ull houses.
Basically, reducing the number of cards per suit reduces the number of flushes faster than it reduces the number of full houses.
In a deck with $s$ suits and $d$ denominations, there are $d(d-1)\binom s3\binom s2$ full houses and $s\cdot \binom d5$ flushes, including straight flushes.
That means whe want to compare
$$\frac{d(d-1)s^2(s-1)^2(s-2)}{12}\quad\color{red}{??}\quad\frac{sd(d-1)(d-2)(d-3)(d-4)}{120}$$
Which is the same as comparing:
$$10s(s-1)^2(s-2)\quad\color{red}{??}\quad (d-2)(d-3)(d-4)$$
With the left/right sides representing the the relative chances of a full house and flush respectively.
When $s=4,$ the left side is $720.$ And as $d\geq 4,$ the right side increases as $d$ increases. When $d=11,$ the right side is $504.$ When $d=12,$ the values are equal. If $d\leq11,$ then the full house is more likely, and, if we discount straight flushes, even when $d=12.$
